# Third Axiom of Probability Explanation

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading my book on probability and it explains the 3rd Axiom as follows:

For any sequence of mutually exclusive events $E_1, E_2, ...$ (that is, events or which $E_iE_j = \emptyset$ when $ i \ne j$ ):

$ P(\  \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i\ )= \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(E_i) $

I know this is an "axiom" which is something assumed to be true.  But usually there is a motivation or insight as to assuming WHY something is the case.  Does anyone have any insights as to why someone would define this axiom or give a motivation for such a case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it is defined in this way, is that Probability spaces are actually measure spaces, and the probability of an event is actually the measure of a set. So if you want to seek WHERE this definition comes from you should study first measure theory.

However, if you want to see why this applies consider a very simple example:

Take a fair die and toss it one time. Then the probability that each side appears is $1/6$. So, if you want the probability of the event $E=E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3$ , where $E_i$ is the event that number $i$ appears is : 
$$P(E)=P(E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 E_i=1/6+1/6+1/6=1/2$$

It is obvious that ,at least, for a finite number of disjoint events **it is natural** to define the probability of the union as the sum of the probabilities.

Can you consider an example with infinite number of disjoint events?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  How in the world do you have an infinite number of disjoint events?

Comment: @user1527227 Upsss!! by mistake I posted my answer as a response to the other answer below.

Answer (score 1):

One way to motivate countable additivity is to look at finite additivity and impose continuity on the measure. I assume you can motivate finite additivity.

**Continuity of measure**: If $A_k$ form an increasing sequence of sets, i.e., $$A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq A_n \subseteq \cdots$$ and $A = \displaystyle\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k$, then we have
$$\mu(A) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n)$$
As always, continuity is a nice thing to have.

Continuity and finite additivity implies countable additivity.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand everything right until you write $\mu(A) $.   What does $\mu$ supposed to represent--is it continuous version of A? Sorry I'm new to probability and all this measure theory stuff.

Comment: @user1527227 In your context, $\mu$ is the probability.

Comment: Suppose we repeat an experiment until we have 1 success. The probability of success is $1/3$ , thus failure has probability $2/3$. What is the probability to have the 1st success after 5 or more trials? 
Write F: Fail, S: Success. Then we want to happen one of the following events: 
FFFFS,FFFFFS,FFFFFFS,FFFFFFFS,$\dots$

So we have an infinite number of disjoint events! What is the probability?
$$P(FFFFS)=2/3\cdot 2/3\cdot2/3\cdot2/3\cdot 1/3=2^4/3^5$$
Do the same for all these events, and the probability that their union happens is : 
$$P=\sum_{n=5}^\infty \dfrac{2^{n-1}}{3^n}$$